# Categorical Labels in KNN sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, knn

I'm working on a classifier using [sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsRegressor](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsRegressor.html).
The data that I use has the following format:

- [numeric_feature1, numeric_feature2, ...., numeric_featureN] [ label_to_predict]

All the features are numerics except the label which i want to predict using KNN.

It is a categorical label with multiple values, for example: 'w1', 'w2', 'w3'.

**My questions are:**

- **Does the KNN support categorical labels or only numerical ones?**
- **In case that it only works with numerical values, is there any right way to encode the labels?**

PD: i know about [sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html) to encode labels but in the documentation says that the categorical values must be hashable and comparable. My labels are just arbitrary words, there is no way to compute a logical distance between them.

PD2: I've tried with categorical labels and i'm getting an error:

"unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'"

Comment: Try MultilabelBinarizer

Comment: Please post the code snippet and full stack trace. Labels are supposed to be categorical, they are not being used in any distance calculation.

Answer (score 0):

Okey, I've found my error.

As i suspect, only numerical labels are supported in [sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsRegressor](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsRegressor.html#sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsRegressor).

But how aberger said in comments in KNN labels are not used in distance.

My error was that I was ussing the class **KNeighborsRegressor** instead of the class **[KNeighborsClassifier](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier.html#sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier)**, which is classification method KNN who accept labels as categorical values.

In the class **KNeighborsRegressor** the the label assigned is computed based the mean of the labels of its nearest neighbors, so it must be numerical.